# How can I plot the H-R diagram of stars

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the Hertzsprung–Russell diagram diagram of stars using Mathematica? Pl. help in the plotting command in details including the process to import data on stars if any

Comment: Well what do you have so far? This website is for the implementation in *Mathematica*, so I would assume you'd already have raw data before wondering about how to code this.

Comment: In principle, use `StarData`.  But `StarData` is so slow that I just don't see how to get all the data in a reasonable amount of time.  The command would be `StarData[EntityClass["Star", All], {"EffectiveTemperature", 
  "AbsoluteMagnitude"}]`.

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful [Evolution of Stars: Hertzsprung-Russell diagram](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/578543)

Answer (score 22):

The difficult bit is finding the data, as Szabolcs points out. Easier to find them online and import them as a dataset:

```
starData = 
  SemanticImport[
   "http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/HIP_star.dat"];
ListPlot[starData[All, {"B-V", "Vmag"}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {"B-V", "v"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {15, 2}}]
```

[image: H-R]

Comment: Yes, but I need a full command, to plot the Luminosity vs Temperature of H-R diagram, including data for main sequence stars number as suitable

Comment: Pl. help me plot the HR diagram given in first page of google search: Main sequence - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia. I need the data along with the plotting command.

Comment: This diagonal across the plot is the main sequence. Now for formatting in the same way as wikipedia I think you need to look at sumit's comment. All in all your question is "how can I plot the H-R diagram of stars and import some data?" and that's exactly what I do here.

Answer (score 9):

In principle, the data can be retrieved within Mathematica using

```
StarData[All, {"EffectiveTemperature", "AbsoluteMagnitude"}]
```

In practice, this command is so slow that it is literally unusable.

Luckily, the older and deprecated [`AstronomicalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AstronomicalData.html) can get you the same data in a couple of minutes.

```
bv = AstronomicalData["Star", "BVColorIndex"];
magn = AstronomicalData["Star", "AbsoluteMagnitude"];

ListPlot[Transpose[{bv, magn}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

@gpap already showed how to format nicely.  This answer is only to show how to get the data using builtin data sources.